# how to update firestore from python appengine

Tags: python, firebase, google-app-engine

I want to update firestore from appengine python . Is there any library in python to this ?

I am trying with firebase-admin but I am getting import errors . How can use firebase-admin in python appengine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Google Cloud Firestore that is in beta release [here](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-firestore/) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/firestore) and also the [Google Cloud Client Libraries for Python](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/firestore/index.html#).

I also recommend that you check the “[how-to](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/how-to#top_of_page)” guide for managing data on Firestore with some sample code to update Firestore.

The public documents do not mention any way to update Firestore using the Firebase-admin. However, I suggest checking the document with more information on projects developed with [App Engine and Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/how-to#top_of_page).